# Using a fork npm package in docker image

Tags: npm, docker-compose, git-fork

I am using a pretty cool npm package react-awesome-query-builder inside one of my docker compose image.  However, there is a small bug that I was able to find an answer for.  I forked the package, made the change and pushed the changes up to my fork.  I then tried modify my package.json to use my forked package

```
"react-awesome-query-builder": "billtlee/react-awesome-query-builder#Material-UI-subgroups",
```

However, when I try to docker-compose build the package, I am getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/billtlee/react-awesome-query-builder.git
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I also tried to use the package on codesandbox.io, but it was complaining as well.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that it's because of git.  I added

```
RUN apk update
RUN apk add git
```

into my dockerfile and it's now working.  Still want to know if anyone knows how to use a forked package in codepen.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when using apt-get. I had to use the -y flag as well as I was getting this error when building the docker container without the -y flag [link](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get):

```
#5 3.783 After this operation, 43.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
#5 3.783 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install git libxml2-utils]: exit code: 1
```

So:

```
RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git
```